# Angular and .Net core application httpPost sends null object

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, http-post

Like the title says, I have an angular application that communicates with a .Net server, and I am having an issue with httpPost. Before I say further, here is the code:

component:

```js
async addStudent() {
    this.studentData = await this.studentService.addStudent(this.newStudentData).toPromise();
}
```

Service:

```js
addStudent(studentNew: Student): Observable<Student[]> {
    return this.http.post<Student[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Student/addStudents', studentNew, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleErrorNew.bind(this)));
```

httpOptions:

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  })
};
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult addStudents([FromBody]Student addStudent)
{
    try
    {
        using (var dbObj= new dataBase())
        {
            dbObj.Add<Student>(addStudent);
            dbObj.SaveChanges();
            var students= new List<Student>();
            try{
                students= dbObj.studentsTable.ToList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return Json(students);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return Json(false);
     }
}
```

Model:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int studentId { get; set; }
    public int studentNum { get; set; }
    public int sectionNum { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public long dateJoined { get; set; }
    public long dateGraduated { get; set; }
}
```

Now, whenever the API is called using the POST from angular, to add to the database, the variable addStudent is for somereason empty.
The call to the action is definitely working, because I am getting the "false" response on the clientside, from the "catch(Exception e)" part of the  server.
`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`
This is what I saw on the console.

Any thoughts on why the server is unable to receive the object? Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

There are a few other POST calls in my application with other models, and surprisingly, all of them are working fine, except this one.

**UPDATE 2**

From further digging into the backend, I have found a few interesting points.
As a start, I have set a breakpoint at the start of the function in the controller, and I have noticed that the entire variable addStudent is literally set to null, not the individual class items in the variable, but the variable as a whole is set to null.

Just as a test, I have then removed the [FromBody] part like this:

```cs
public IActionResult addStudents(Student addStudent)
```

and now, when I run the application with the breakpoint and viewed the variable addStudent, all the class items are being displayed, but the values of all the items are null, or 0 depending on the type of the variable.

Comment: If you could edit your question and show us what's the data is would be helpful, otherwise are you 100% sure it's correct? Also provide your Student object model as well.

Comment: @penleychan I am 100% sure it is correct because I checked it letter by letter. And I have edited the question with the model.

Comment: Confused, `[FromBody]Student` different object than `Tracking`?

Comment: Is your backend api working in postman

Comment: @penleychan sorry, typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda Yes, surprisingly, I have a few other POST calls, that are all working with other models. Only this one doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a debug to see which value is NULL, is it addStudent is NULL or one of property is NULL?

It feels like it's because of the framework not able to create an instance of Student object based on the post body.

Have a look at the client side to see the exactly data that post and check the server side see how is the addStudent looks like

FYI

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#input-formatters

Comment: That actually helped understand the problem a little better. I have updated the question with the debug results. Please have a look. Thank you

Comment: Did you check the data you post to server? It feels like is data issue to me

Comment: Yes, I figured it. It was a data issue. One of the data types I was sending was wrongly assigned. And So, I got a null value. Debugging it helped me to figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET Core then you're missing this little attribute in your API controller shown below.
[image]

Otherwise i you're not interested to add this line please write your controller like below

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("PostCustomer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer) // Add [FromBody] attribute before parameter.
    {
        // Do Some Code
        return Ok();
    }
```